# Projection onto level set of convex functional

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, hilbert-spaces, convexity, convex-analysis

Fix a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and let $F:L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ be bounded-blow, convex, lower semi-continuous, and not identically infinite (but also not everywhere finite).  Fix a constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the associated level-set
$$
C:=\left\{
 g \in L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathcal{F}):\, F(g)\leq c
\right\},
$$
is non-empty.

Since $F$ is lower semi-continuous and convex then we know that $C$ is closed and convex and since $L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathcal{F})$ is a Hilbert space then standard results imply that there is a (well-defined) Lipschitz metric-projection operator:
$$
P_C:L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathcal{F})\ni g 
\to \operatorname{argmin}_{\tilde{g}\in C}\, \mathbb{E}\big[\|\tilde{g}-g\|^2\big].
$$

Are the efficient algorithms for computing this projection (given only this information)?

Comment: Any answer depends a lot about what you assume to be possible. Are gradients of $F$ available (and fast to compute)? How costly is the evaluation of $F$? Can you minimize linear functionals over $C$? If the proximal map available? You can always form the Lagrange functional and try to solve the respective optimality system…

Comment: I guess I can assume that F's gradients are available